# how do I make my answer on a single line instead of four separate lines

Tags: java

so I have made a script which is telling if a line is below, above or on equal to a y value. However i want to be able to put in my values on a single line so that it would be like 3, 6, 7, 9   something like that. and so when you press enter it will put out the answer. my code:

```
package computing.line.linetest;

/**  * Created by Jakob on 07-02-2015.  */ public class LineTest {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
            java.util.Scanner tastatur = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Indsæt a, x, b og y værdierne her og tryk retur");
        int a, x, b, y;
        a = tastatur.nextInt();
        x = tastatur.nextInt();
        b = tastatur.nextInt();
        y = tastatur.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("a er "+a+", x er "+x+", b er "+b+", y er "+y+"");
            if (a * x + b == y) System.out.println("Linje");
            else if (a * x + b > y) System.out.println("Under");
            else System.out.println("Over");
    } }
```

Comment: it should be noted that the language used is danish not english :)

Comment: Use `print` instead of `println` in all except your last print. Or print the line feed separately at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already accepts the numbers on a single line. `Scanner.nextInt()` will not scan the entire line but only the next integer token, so you don't need to press Enter after every number.

If the commas are required, one way is to read the line and split it around the comma delimiter to obtain an array of tokens. Then you would assign each token as an integer to each of the four variables:

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
String[] numbers = input.split(",");
int a, x, b, y;
a = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0].trim());
x = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1].trim());
b = Integer.parseInt(numbers[2].trim());
y = Integer.parseInt(numbers[3].trim());
```

The `trim` method is used to remove whitespace if it exists before or after the comma.

Comment: Instead of pressing enter after every number, you can just type "3 6 7 9" without commas and then press enter and they will all be saved accordingly to your variables.

Comment: what if I want it to require colon after each number?

Comment: @JakobSchøler In this case you can read the whole line and split it into tokens using the comma as a delimiter. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Scanner Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) has it's own parsing capablities , So You can give the inputs in the `same line` or in `different line` it will parse automatically

```
   int a, x, b, y;
    a = tastatur.nextInt();
    x = tastatur.nextInt();
    b = tastatur.nextInt();
    y = tastatur.nextInt();
```

**This will work for both inputs**

```
1 2 3 4
```

**as well as for**

```
1
2
3
4
```